# Annotation for nullable reference with generics

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

Given the following generic `Foo1` function:

```
struct Key<T> {}
static readonly Key<double> MyKey = new Key<double>();
T? Foo1<T>(Key<T> key)
{
    return default;
}
```

A naive reader would assume that:

```
var foo1 = Foo1(MyKey);
```

`foo1` is of type `double?`, it turns out that the compiler is picking `double` for the return type. I need to explictly add a constraint to get a nullable return value:

```
T? Foo2<T>(Key<T> key) where T : struct // really return a nullable
{
    return default;
}
```

Could someone explain why the annotation for nullable reference `?` is not being picked up in my first `Foo1` function ?

Comment: Probably nullable reference types are activated, otherwise signature `T? Foo2<T>(Key<T> key)` - without the struct constraint - wouldn't compile.
For inferring type arguments, only input values and their compile-time types are checked - return types are ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with some background:

Before C# 9.0 `Foo1` was invalid. Even in C# 8.0 with enabled nullable references:

```
CS8627: A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type
```

`Foo2` was valid even before C# 8.0 because `T?` made sense only if `T` was a struct, and in this case `T?` had a different type from `T` (`Nullable<T>`). So far, it's quite simple.

Starting with C# 8.0 nullable references have been introduced, which caused some confusion. From now on `T?` can either mean `Nullable<T>` or just `T`. This version didn't allow `T?` without a constraint but it allowed also when you specified `where T : class`.

Without using constraints you had to use attributes to indicate that `T` can be `null` as a return value:

```
// C# 8.0: Poor man's T?
[return: MaybeNull] T Foo1<T>(Key<T> key) => default;
```

And what if `T` is a value type now? It clearly will not change its type to `Nullable<T>` in the return value. To return a `double?` your type argument must also be `double?`, meaning, `MyKey` must also be a `Key<double?>`.

In C# 9.0 the restriction for `T?` has been relaxed, now it does not need a constraint:

```
// C# 9.0: this is valid now
T? Foo1<T>(Key<T> key) => default;
```

But it essentially now means the same as the C# 8.0 version. Without the `where T : struct` constraint `T?` is the same type as `T` so it is nothing but an indication that the result can be `null`, which can appear in compiler warnings. To return nullable value types you must use `double?` as a generic argument, which also mean that your `Key` also must have a nullable type defined:

```
static readonly Key<double?> MyKey = new Key<double?>();
```

If a nullable key makes no sense in your case, then you cannot do anything but specifying `where T : struct` constraint as in `Foo2` so the old rule kicks in: `T?` and `T` have different types where `T?` means `Nullable<T>`.

---

**Update:** The main difference between `Foo1` and `Foo2` is maybe more obvious if you see their [decompiled source](https://sharplab.io/#gist:627710dfc77e3c84a7b8429c72196a4c):

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
private static T Foo1<T>([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(new byte[] {
    0,
    1
})] Key<T> key)
{
    return default(T);
}

private static Nullable<T> Foo2<T>(Key<T> key) where T : struct
{
    return null;
}
```

Note that the return type of `Foo1` is simply `T` with some annotation so the compiler can emit the proper warnings.