# Function returning nullable generic type not returning correct type

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm trying to define a function that returns a nullable version of the value passed in, and then apply it with a boolean.

```cs
using System;

#nullable enable

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Test(true, true) ?? false);
    }
    
    public static A? Test<A>(A val, bool useNull) =>
        useNull ? default(A?) : val;
}
```

However, this gives me the error:

> Compilation error (line 11, col 21): Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'

But I'm not quite clear on *why* this error is being given - after all `Test()` should return type `bool?`, not `bool`, and so using `??` should be perfectly legal.

Is this a bug in the C# nullable values feature, or am I misunderstanding how it's supposed to work?

For what it's worth, if I rewrite `Test()` to be non-generic, it seems to work:

```cs
public static bool? Test(bool val, bool useNull) => 
    useNull ? null : val;
```

But I'm trying to understand why the generic version doesn't work.

Comment: You can make it work for all value types using `public static A? Test<A>(A val, bool useNull) where A : struct
        => useNull ? null : val;`. The same function with a type constraint `where A: class` will also work for reference types.

Comment: @Mushroomator - that's good to know, but I am trying to understand _why_ this behavior exists as opposed to a workaround :). But thanks for the tip.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/69211372/5114784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: You can make it work once you use type constraints `class` and `struct` for value respectively reference types in two separate functions.

```cs
namespace MyProgram;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(NullableValueType(true, true) ?? false);
        Console.WriteLine(NullableReferenceType(new object(), true) ?? false);
    }

    public static A? NullableValueType<A>(A val, bool useNull) where A : struct
        => useNull ? null : val;


    public static A? NullableReferenceType<A>(A val, bool useNull) where A : class
            => useNull ? null : val;
}
```

Now why doesn't this work in a single method without the type constraints?

Well, it has to do with the way the Nullable feature is implemented for value types in contrast to reference types. Reference types are nullable by design (the implementation of the Nullable feature here is basically just a bunch of Attributes that the compiler can use to be smart about what can and cannot be null), whereas value types cannot be null. And in fact, a nullable value type itself is never `null`. It is implemented by using the [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-7.0) struct and [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#boxing-and-unboxing).

It gets clearer when you look at the [lowered C#](https://mattwarren.org/2017/05/25/Lowering-in-the-C-Compiler/) the compiler generates using e.g. [Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io) (here the relevant excerpt from what the C# compiler generates from above code):

```cs
namespace MyProgram
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NullableValueType(true, true).GetValueOrDefault());
            Console.WriteLine(NullableReferenceType(new object(), true) ?? ((object)false));
        }

        public static Nullable<A> NullableValueType<A>(A val, bool useNull) where A : struct
        {
            return useNull ? null : new Nullable<A>(val);
        }

        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
        [return: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(2)]
        public static A NullableReferenceType<A>(A val, bool useNull) where A : class
        {
            return useNull ? null : val;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the return types are different due to how nullable value/ reference types are implemented and therefore you cannot unify this into a single method.

> Disclaimer: I dug into this when I saw the question as I was also surprised at first by this behavior and this is the explanation I came up with from looking at the lowered code. Feel free to add/ correct if required.

Comment: Wild, really interesting that it gets desugared into two different things. And it seems to use the `class` one by default then (since it interprets the return type as just `bool` instead of `bool?`) which would seem to be buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this and to be fair I think the compiler perceives the A parameter as ANY type parameter and not a value type parameter in general and you're looking to make it think it's a nullable value type parameter specifically.
It currently sees it as a bool in your case and ?? cannot be applied to a bool.

You can add a constraint to the A generic type of Test

`static A? Test<A>(A val, bool useNull) where A : struct`

The reason we use struct is because ?? is designed to be used with nullable value types and struct is a nullable value type.